# Separate billing/shipping addresses in magento?

Tags: php, magento

One of customers contacted him to point out that he is not able to specify different billing and shipping addresses for his account.  When he changes one address, the other automatically changes as well.

I logged into the Magento admin console to try and separate the addresses myself, but I didn’t find a way.

Any Idea!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn’t fix the problem so I ended up just displaying a message to users. It only shows the message when they have one address in their address book.

To implement this fix using the default Magento theme, insert the code below in app/design/frontend/your-interface/your-theme/template/customer/address/edit.phtml

```
<?php if($this->isDefaultBilling() && $this->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
<ul>
    <li class="error-msg">Editing this address will update both your billing and shipping address. If you want to add an entirely new billing or shipping address click <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl();?>customer/address/new/" title="Create New Billing or Shipping Address">here</a>.</li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

it's working..

Comment: Basically, as you found, all you can do is have some sort of message alerting the customer to this odd user interface behavior. Our customers found it to be very confusing. Magento has a single address in the book, if you want a different ship/bill address, you must add an address and then check it as to what it is the default for.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh. If you want to go with this solution and put it into a CMS Block: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('customer-account-address-change-alert')->toHtml(); ?>

CMS BLOCK (customer-account-address-change-alert):
<ul>
<li class="error-msg">Editing this address will update both your billing and shipping address. If you want to add an entirely new billing or shipping address click <a style="" title="Create New Billing or Shipping Address" href="{{store direct_url="customer/address/new"}}">here</a>.</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but the handling is indeed not very nice. If you currently have the same billing and shipping address and edit one of them, indeed both addresses are updated.

If you want to edit only one address, you have to add a new address. If you do so, you can configure this new address to be the default billing / shipping address.